# Apache Camel : using throttle : how to change the value of timePeriodMillis using a config file?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, blueprint-osgi, throttling

i use the throttle in apache camel blueprint : throttle timePeriodMillis="1000" 
with constant = 4 
i want to put the value of timePeriodMillis dynamically using placeholder.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

And the section *Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL*

Answer (score 0):

Properties component can be used here

ex:

```
Properties properties = new Properties(); 
InputStream input = null;


public void configure() throws IOException {

   CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();    

   input = new FileInputStream("sample.properties");
   properties.load(input);

   System.out.println("CITY IS" +properties.getProperty("wl.city"));
   String city = properties.getProperty("wl.city");
```